# Prevent the timer from resetting

Tags: javascript, jscript

I'm making a countdown timer script that exits the program when the time reaches 0.

The problem is that when the page reloaded the timer starts again from the beginning..

Is there any way to prevent the timer from resetting?

```
  // set the date we're counting down to
  var target_date = new Date().getTime();
  var delay=100;
  // variables for time units
  var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

  // get tag element
  var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

  // update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
  setInterval(function () {

        // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
        var seconds_left = (current_date - target_date) / 1000;
        var a=(delay-seconds_left);
        // do some time calculations

        minutes = parseInt(a / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(a % 60);
        var progress = a/delay*100;

        // format countdown string + set tag value
        countdown.innerHTML = '<div  Class=outer style="font-size:20px;width:'+progress+'%">'+minutes + "m: " + seconds + "s" + '</div>';

        if(a <= 0)
        {
        window.open("a.html")

        self.close();
        //var wind = window.open("a.html");    
        }

  }, 1000);
```

Comment: *"Is there any way to prevent the timer from resetting?"* is a very different question than your title *"Preventing refresh"* suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `target_date` in local storage (or a cookie) and look for it on page load. E.g.:

```
var target_date = localStorage.target_date;
if (target_date) {
    // Found it in local storage, turn the string into a number
    target_date = parseInt(target_date);
} else {
    // Didn't find it in local storage, get the target and 
    target_date = new Date().getTime(); // See below, this looks weird
    localStorage.target_date = String(target_date);
}
```

Local storage is [quite well-supported in modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

Note that only strings and certain other storage-compatible items can be stored in local storage, which is why I'm explicitly dealing with a string version of the number above. If you need to store more complex information, JSON is usually a useful format.

---

Your code initializing `target_date` doesn't make much sense to me: It grabs the time **now**. I would expect a countdown to grab a time *in the future* for `target_date`. In any case, replace that line (or replace what you're storing) as necessary.

Comment: it gets the time when the page opens and then current_date gets the date every second.It computes the difference between the times; when the time interval is greater than the delay time given the program stops.

Comment: @user3852052: Ah, gotcha. Then the above should work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could always put the current time into a cookie and load that cookie when loading the page.
[Learn more about Cookies here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: [Cookies.js](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies) makes it super easy to set and get values from cookies. Without it, you would likely have to write your own functions or set values in a special format with expiration times.

Comment: There are already the getCookie(), setCookie() and checkCookie() functions in the link i posted. They are super easy to understand and to use.